# $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1-x^{-2n}}{1+x^{-2n}} $

Tags: calculus

$ \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1-x^{-2n}}{1+x^{-2n}} $, x $\gt $0

1.1

2.-1

3.0

4 limit does not exist.

My attempt: here if x is between o and 1 then limit is -1 and if x is more than 1 limit  is 1. But option are not matching. Plz help. Thanks

Comment: the answer depends on whether $x$ is greater than one or not. even think about if $x=1$

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{1-x^{-2n}}{1+x^{-2n}}\cdot\frac{x^{2n}}{x^{2n}}=\frac{x^{2n}-1}{x^{2n}+1}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} \begin{cases}?&,\;\;0<x<1\\{}\\?&,\;\;x=1\\{}\\?&,\;\;x>1\end{cases}$$

Comment: This works . But options were not coming. I think options are wrong. None of them is true

Comment: Well, **all** the options appear there according to the three cases written in the answer...