# $\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{1-x^{-2n}}{1+x^{-2n}}$ $,x>0$

Tags: limits

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{1-\frac{1}{x^{2n}}}{1+\frac{1}{x^{2n}}}$

$\therefore$ When $x=1$, The numerator is $0$ , and hence $\lim=0$

When $x>1$, the numerator and denominator is $1$, and $\lim=1$

But my question is: What about when $0<x<1$ ?

Comment: I wonder why the downvote. Just because it may be obvious to some, that's no good reason to downvote anonymously, rather than posting a hint or an answer.

Comment: Duplicate: [$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \dfrac{1-x^{-2n}}{1+x^{-2n}},\,x\gt0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1136169/201168). (*Found using [Approach0.xyz](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24\lim_{n%20\to%20\infty}%20\dfrac{1-x^{-2n}}{1%2Bx^{-2n}}%24&p=1)*)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have: $\dfrac{x^{2n}-1}{x^{2n}+1}\to -1$, because $x^{2n} \to 0$.